# How to instsall nix-linter

Tags: nix

I've tried to install nix-linter with 3 way. None works

**nix package manager**

```
 nix-env -iA nixpkgs.nix-linter
```

> Package is marked as broken, refusing to evaluate.

It propose me several option to add broken package (  export NIXPKGS_ALLOW_BROKEN=1 ). But I don't understand exactly what will be the repercutions. I prefer not to follow this option

**with cachix**

I follow this [tutorial](https://app.cachix.org/cache/nix-linter)

and add this line

```
echo "trusted-users = root myusername" | sudo tee -a /etc/nix/nix.conf && sudo pkill nix-daemon
```

normally after `cachix use nix-linter` there is a cache that `nix-build` use

But it doesn't work. I get an error saying that there is no default.nix in my repository

**https://github.com/Synthetica9/nix-linter**

cachix use nix-linter
git clone https://github.com/Synthetica9/nix-linter
cd nix-linter
$(nix-build -A nix-linter)/bin/nix-linter --help

> error: attribute 'nix-linter' in selection path 'nix-linter' not found
> -bash: /bin/nix-linter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somebody from cacheix said that this package is no longer maintain and I should try statix.

statix works